# How to filter an array without losing the index?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" #searchBox class="form-control chapter-filter" placeholder="Search chapter..." name="chapter" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
```

  {{chapter?.name}}'

** on the basic of *searchText* I am filtering the chapter**

**search-filter.pipe.ts**

```
transform(items, searchText, searchField: string) {
let filteredList = [];
if (searchText) {
    return items.filter(item => {
        searchText = searchText.trim().toLowerCase();
        let itemName = item[searchField].trim().toLowerCase();

        if (itemName.indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
            filteredList.push(item);
            return filteredList;
        }
    })
} else {
    return items;
}
```

}

**The problem is when I filter any chapter it is working fine, but the index of chapter is set according to filtered chapters.**
*-->
Suppose I have 3 chapters*

1. one  ( index - 0 )
2. two   ( index - 1 )
3. three  ( index - 2 )

and when I enter **three**, it shows only three. thats right but its index is 0 now.
**How can I make it remain index 2. I mean it should filter but should not change index.**

Comment: Why not just make `chapterIndex` a property of `Chapter`? If you dont want this, I think you should not use the searchFilter pipe, but do the filter logic in your component, having a allChapters and filteredChapters array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here.

1. Pass chapter to the click handler

```
<li (click)="changeChapter(chapter)" *ngFor="let chapter of chapters | searchFilter">
```

and lookup index in the original array

```
changeChapter(chapter) { 
   this.chapterIndex = this.chapters.indexOf(chapter);
  // and whatever ...
}
```

2. Make chapterIndex a property of `Chapter`

```
<li (click)="changeChapter(chapter)" *ngFor="let chapter of chapters | searchFilter">
   {{ chapter.chapterIndex }} - {{ chapter.name }}
</li>
```

3. Do the filter logic inside your component

```
<li (click)="changeChapter(chapter)" *ngFor="let chapter of displayedChapters">
</li>
```

```
displayedChapters: Chapter[];
private allChapters: Chapter[];

changeChapter() {
   // whatever happens here...
}
```

Comment: But the thing is I have something inside in <li> tag that requires index. 
<i class="las la-circle" *ngIf="!isActive('chapter' ,C_i) && !chap.isCompleted"></i>

thats requires index.

Comment: is there any way that I can filter also and keep the index as it was initialy

Comment: @Karan Yes, option 2. and 3.